# Installed Ubuntu 15.10, but it doesn't boot

Tags: boot, 15.10

I successfully got rid of Windows 8, and installed Ubuntu 15.10, but it won't boot unless I use the a usb boot. How can I get it to boot without using the usb?

Comment: Might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: That's not a whole lot of information to work with. What's is it doing? How far into the boot process is it going? Are you getting error messages? If so, what's the message or messages?

Comment: If I don't put the usb in, I get a message saying "insert book device", and nothing else happens. I have to restart with the usb or it doesn't boot. I tried reinstalling several times, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating the obvious here; did you actually install Ubuntu or just "try" it by running it from the USB?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can have an terminal acess via USB. Try this:

$ sudo fdisk -l

then, see what partition you have the ubuntu installed(ext4 filetype) then:

$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda6 /mnt (admitting that sda6 is my ubuntu partition)

and then

$ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda

this will reinstall grub and see all the others OS' that you have and organize all of them.